# How to make kendo-ui angular grid responsive

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

I would like to make kendu-ui angular grid responsive using media queries and when I try to make the screen smaller there is an unexplicable large space at the right.

It works well on full screen but not bellow 1400px, It doesn't take all the available space at the right of the screen (see attached image).

I tried this:

```
.k-grid {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and this:

```
.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-lg,
.container-md,
.container-sm,
.container-xl,
.container-xxl {
  width: 100%;
}
```

but it doesn't make any change.

How to make the grid take all the available space at the right?

[image]